# Docker and Zappa: Wrong python path

Tags: python, django, docker, zappa

I'm trying to run Django in a Lambda using Zappa and Docker, I'm following the instructions [outlined here](https://romandc.com/zappa-django-guide/setup/).

When I run `zappa deploy dev` I keep getting the FileNotFound error below. It looks like my pythonpath and virtual environment path is wrong, and I've no idea how it got in there. I tried setting the pythonpath in my Dockerfile but with no luck.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2779, in handle
    sys.exit(cli.handle())
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 509, in handle
    self.dispatch_command(self.command, stage)
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 546, in dispatch_command
    self.deploy(self.vargs['zip'])
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 718, in deploy
    self.create_package()
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/cli.py", line 2216, in create_package
    archive_format='tarball'
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/core.py", line 544, in create_lambda_zip
    copytree(cwd, temp_project_path, metadata=False, symlinks=False, ignore=shutil.ignore_patterns(*excludes))
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/utilities.py", line 63, in copytree
    copytree(s, d, metadata, symlinks, ignore)
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/utilities.py", line 63, in copytree
    copytree(s, d, metadata, symlinks, ignore)
  File "/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/zappa/utilities.py", line 65, in copytree
    shutil.copy2(s, d) if metadata else shutil.copy(s, d)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 248, in copy
    copyfile(src, dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/shutil.py", line 120, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/task/env/bin/python'
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM lambci/lambda:build-python3.7
LABEL maintainer="email@gmail.com"
WORKDIR /var/task
RUN echo 'export PS1="\[\e[36m\]zappashell>\[\e[m\] "' >> /root/.bashrc
ENV PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/var/task/venv/lib/python3.7"
CMD ["bash"]
```

zappa_settings.json

```
{
    "dev": {
        "django_settings": "myapp.settings",
        "profile_name": null,
        "project_name": "myapp",
        "runtime": "python3.7",
        "s3_bucket": "zappa-myapp",
        "aws_region": "us-east-1",
        "slim_handler": true,
        "include": [],
        "exclude": [".env"],
        "apigateway_enabled": true,
        "use_precompiled_packages": false,             
    }
}
```

Comment: That Dockerfile seems incomplete; it doesn't seem to `COPY` the task's code in or set the `CMD` to run it.  In general you also don't need virtual environments and Docker together since the Docker image itself provides isolation from other Python installations.  Do you have a more complete Dockerfile that produces a runnable image, and that still produces that error?

Comment: Thank you, I believe that is because I'm using the shell in the Docker container to run Zappa. And it looks like Zappa needs to be run in a virtual environment to deploy Django to an AWS Lambda "Zappa will automatically package up your application and local virtual environment into a Lambda-compatible archive, replace any dependencies with versions with wheels compatible with lambda..." [source](https://github.com/zappa/Zappa#initial-deployments).

Comment: The error is looking for ‘env’ - maybe a typo in Zappa settings?  Can you post that?  Also did you activate the environment inside the docket instance?

Comment: Ah yes that was part of the problem, I had two virtual environments (I thought I needed a separate env for Zappa). Now I just have one 'env', and I'm still getting a Python path error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/name/Documents/code/myapp/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages'` I'll add the Zappa settings to my original post

Comment: @n_ck glad there is progress.  I would now remove the PYTHONPATH from your docker file and rebuild your image.  I see you're excluding `.env` - maybe this is confusing the tool.  Try to recreate the virtual environment using `venv` or `ve`.  And be sure to do this within the Docker instance.

Comment: Thanks! Re-creating the virtual environment (and removing the PYTHONPATH from the docker file) worked. Thanks for your help @Edgar, I'll also post it below so I can mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I initially had two virtual environments, one existing and one newly created for Docker. The solution was to remove the PYTHONPATH variable from the Dockerfile, deleting both virtual environments and creating a new one.